Green's function of the conformal Laplacian
I am reading T. Parker, S. Rosenberg, "Invariants of conformal Laplacians", J. Differential Geom. 25(2): 199-222 (1987). I would like to understand how Green function changes if the metric undergoes a conformal change. It seems to me that Eq. (1.4) of this paper is the desirable expression that I am looking for which says the following: Let $(M,g)$ denote a n-dimensional Riemannian manifold. Consider a conformal structure on $M$ which is an equivalence class of metrics with $g_1 = e^{2f} g$, where $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$. Then we have the following relation for the corresponding Green functions:
\begin{equation}
G(x,y)_{e^{2f}g}= G_{g}(x,y)\, e^{-(n/2-1)(f(x)+f(y))}.
\end{equation}
I would like to apply this relation to 2-sphere. Using the stereographic projection, one has
\begin{equation}
g_{ij}= \Omega\,\delta_{ij},\qquad \Omega = \frac{4}{(1+x_1^2+x_2^2)^2}\,.
\end{equation}
In this case $n/2-1=0$, then the exponential part will vanish. I wonder how should I interpret the associated Green functions? Is there any books/lecture notes where I can read more about such problems? Thank you very much.
